# Sensu log files growing to enormous sizes

Tags: logging, sensu

My sensu-client.log files are growing to ridiculous sizes like 1.7 GB plus and it is taking up a lot of unnecessary space.

Does anyone know how to set an option to limit the file size or have an additional suggestion to control this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can configure sensu log level by setting `LOG_LEVEL` in `/etc/default/sensu` to either `debug`, `info`, `warn` or `error`.

You will need to restart the sensu-client (`service sensu-client restart`) after making the change.

Comment: I tried this setting the LOG_LEVEL=error in /etc/default/sensu and after restarting the service is still logs everything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What kind of log entry do you have there ?

Comment: {"timestamp":"2014-12-03T12:01:47.584546+0000","level":"info","message":"received check request","check":{"name":"memory_percent_check","issued":1417608107,"command":"/etc/sensu/plugins/system/check-memory-pcnt.sh -c 80 -w 70"}}
{"timestamp":"2014-12-03T12:01:58.080922+0000","level":"warn","message":"received signal","signal":"TERM"}
{"timestamp":"2014-12-03T12:01:58.081110+0000","level":"warn","message":"stopping"}
{"timestamp":"2014-12-03T12:01:58.081379+0000","level":"info","message":"completing checks in progress","checks_in_progress":[]}

Comment: Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: What kind of system do you have ? Ubuntu, CentOS or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @KrzysztofSzarek's answer, putting `LOG_LEVEL=warn` in `/etc/default/sensu`, you may also specify the log level on the command line when starting sensu-server/sensu-api/sensu-client, e.g. `-L warn`

See the corresponding [code on Github](https://github.com/sensu/sensu/blob/master/lib/sensu/cli.rb).